# What does QueueMO API actually do?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

The documentation is very scarce: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/postQueueMO.html does it trigger an Outbound SMS message FROM the shortcode to the mobile number provided in the payload? Or, as MO would suggest, the other way round, records an action (response) of a certain recipient number (eg. STOP) on the keyword in MobileConnect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MO term stands for 'mobile originated', it's the inbound mobile message sent by subscribers.

[Reference](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sms-messaging-with-mobileconnect/get-to-know-sms)

> Inbound Message
>
> Mobile-originated (MO) messages are sent by customers from their phone. Inbound messages require two-way communication availability.

You can use this API to let people opt in/opt out (through a web form for example). So, it is the second point that you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Thanks. But at the end of the day, is an SMS message triggered TO the person who provided consent through a web form? So let's imagine I collect people phone numbers in a web form, can I trigger the QueueMO to both subscribe them AND send them the first message from the keyword of my choosing?

Comment: Like I mentioned in my answer. It is the inbound mobile message, not outbound msg. So basically, it doesn't send anything to the subscriber but the MC system. You can create a separate mobile msg to capture the queue MO send so it can send a confirmation msg after that. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_moc_mobile_opt-in.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly opposite to what SF Support told me btw, they said you can send an SMS directly from the API, but I get your point and that's how I thought it works after checking what MO stands for. That being said, in the payload of the QueueMO why is there a messageText prop? where is that stored? "Mobile opt-in" template type in MobileConnect picks those QueueMO records up?

Comment: messageText property is to use for Opt In/Opt Out in Mobile Connect channel. E.g. you put your keyword in messageText , then if it will be captured in a Mobile Opt-In msg you created for that keyword, and then you are opted in. You can try it yourself to experience

Comment: Like instead of the real person texts a keyword to your Short/Long code to opt it/opt out, you do it for them through the API